# Dependeny Injection Error - Unable to resolve service ... for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting a Dependency Injection Error when testing WebAPI project

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'EF_Events.Models.EventDBContext' while attempting to activate 'EventsAPI.Controllers.EventsController'.

I have two separate projects in my solution. The EF project and an API project that references the EF project.

EventsController.cs (in API project)

```
public class EventsController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly Services.IEventService _service;
    private readonly EventDBContext _eventContext;
    private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepository;

    public EventsController(EventDBContext context)
    {
        _eventContext = context;
        _eventRepository = new EventRepository(_eventContext);
        _service = new Services.EventService(_eventRepository);
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        //   return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        var events = _service.GetAllEvents();
        return Ok(events);

    }
}
```

EventService.cs (in API project)

```
namespace EventsAPI.Services
{
    public class EventService : IEventService
    {
        private readonly IEventRepository _rep;

        public EventService(IEventRepository eventRepository)
        {
            _rep = eventRepository;
        }

        public List<Event> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return _rep.GetAllEvents();
        }

        //public Event GetEventDetail(int id)
        //{
        //    return _rep.GetEventDetail(id);

        //}
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (in EF Project)

```
services.AddDbContext<EventDBContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddScoped<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
```

EventRepository.cs (in EF Project)

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{

    private readonly EventDBContext _eventContext;

    public EventRepository(EventDBContext context)
    {
        _eventContext = context;
    }

    public List<Event> GetAllEvents()
    {
        return _eventContext.Events.ToList();
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong; I have checked several posts here and on other sites. It looks like I have the Startup.cs correct, but it is just not working.

Comment: The exact error is this

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'EF_Events.Models.EventDBContext' while attempting to activate 'EventsAPI.Controllers.EventsController'.

Comment: Is `DefaultConnection` a valid connection string?

Comment: Yes, it is valid.  I was able to generate the DB.

Comment: Do you have more than one class called `EventDBContext`?

Comment: No, I have only one class with that name

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your startup.cs where you add the DBContext and see if it actually runs when hitting F5?

Comment: I would also say you might need to put the entire project into a github repo just quickly because at this point it could unfortunately be anything :\

Comment: I have breakpoints in the StartUp.cs and they never get hit

Comment: are you using debug build?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments on your post that when debugging the breakpoints in startup.cs are not hit.

Can you confirm you add the Startup class to the WebHostBuilder configuration in program.cs?

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>() // This line
        .Build();

    host.Run();
```

Edit:

Controller:

```
 private readonly Services.IEventService _service;


public EventsController(IEventService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

In EF project add ServiceCollectionExtension class:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddEFProject(this IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(o => o.UseSql //....);
    services.AddScoped<IRepo, Repo>();
    return services;
}
```

Then in your other project reference EF project & add services to the collection

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddEfProject();
```

Comment: Yes, I have that line in my Program.cs in my EF project

Comment: And is the IEventService registered and added to the container? `Services.AddScoped<..>` ? Also, you don't need to inject everything in the controller, just the service you are calling. The IoC container takes care of the rest. It will resolve the Repository and Context in the background.

Comment: The EventRepository is scoped in the Startup.cs.  However, when debugging, it the context is null

Comment: Thanks for the code
I think I left out some important information on my original post, it will edit.
I have 2 projects in my solution, an EF project, and an API project which has a reference to the EF project.  So because of that, I cannot scope the Service only the Repository

Comment: ServiceCollectionExtensionPattern: In this case you need to add a ServiceCollectionExtension to your EF project. Call it 'Add*EfProjectName*. Then in the startup of your other project add Services.Add*EfProjectName* so those services are also resolved in the container. See: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/24/servicecollection-extension-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller constructor to;

```
public EventsController(IEventDBContext context)
{
    _eventContext = context;
    _eventRepository = new EventRepository(_eventContext);
    _service = new Services.EventService(_eventRepository);
}
```

Also your repository constructor to;

```
public EventRepository(IEventDBContext context)
{
    _eventContext = context;
}
```

Then, DI will inject correct db context.